# Identify AES Algorithm . Is it AES 128 or AES 256?

Tags: c#, aes

I am using AES Algorithm for Encryption & Decryption in c# .I am using **AesCryptoServiceProvider** class for Encryption & decryption.

Here is my settings in the code

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider result = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
result.BlockSize = 128;
result.KeySize = 256;
result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```

I am little confused whether the code i am using here is implementation of  AES 128 or AES 256 .

Simple question is **How to identify you are using AES 256 / AES 128 ?**

I tried this link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac5f4d30-343e-484e-b795-b214820a9327/aes-net-encryption-is-it-always-256-bit-aes

But i didn't got my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's AES 256. The number is the key size.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard):

> Strictly speaking, the AES standard is a variant of Rijndael where the block size is restricted to 128 bits.

So the block size is *always* 128.

---

I can't point you to any official documentation because (so far as I'm aware) `AES-<Number>` has always been an *unofficial* shorthand. I can point you at a Bruce Schneier [Blog Post](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html) which quotes a research paper:

> AES is the best known and most widely used block cipher. Its three versions (AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256) differ in their key sizes (128 bits, 192 bits and 256 bits) and in their number of rounds (10, 12, and 14, respectively). In the case of ...

Although your client may not like the rest of that blog post since it's Schneier recommending AES-128 over AES-256.

Comment: So does that mean i am using AES 256 Algorithm here but not AES 128 ?

Comment: Is there any documentation on this to prove ? My lead is not convinced with this . Also on Wikipedia link they haven't mentioned any relation b/w Algorithm & Key Size

Comment: @Manju - *given* that the block size for AES is fixed at 128, but the key sizes for AES are allowed to be 128, 192 or 256, what is your lead's proposed construction for what the difference is between AES 128 and AES 256?

Comment: I mean how do you identify the algorithm you are using is AES 256 / AES 128. Solely based on KeySize ?
I don’t see any documentation which says Key Size is the parameter which decides the algorithm you are using (.i.e. AES 256/AES 128). Can you direct me to any documentation ?  My Client is very specific about AES 256

Comment: My answer quotes  FIPS-197. That's rather authoritative even if it does not *officially* name the "flavors".

Answer (score 4):

The official specification of AES is FIPS-197. It contains the following text regarding the key size and block size.

```
1. Introduction

This standard specifies the Rijndael algorithm ([3] and [4]), a symmetric block cipher that can
process data blocks of 128 bits, using cipher keys with lengths of 128, 192, and 256 bits.
Rijndael was designed to handle additional block sizes and key lengths, however they are not
adopted in this standard.

Throughout the remainder of this standard, the algorithm specified herein will be referred to as
“the AES algorithm.” The algorithm may be used with the three different key lengths indicated
above, and therefore these different “flavors” may be referred to as “AES-128”, “AES-192”, and
“AES-256”.
```

As NIST choose Rijndael to be AES after a contest, you cannot get a more authoritative reference.

Note that although your code also contains CBC and PKCS#7 padding, those are not part of the specification of the AES. CBC is an approved block cipher mode of operation by NIST (see NIST SP 800-38A) though. That specification also mentions that padding schemes are not taken into account by NIST, probably because they should not be used as an algorithm providing any security (for block cipher modes, that is).